# How can I move repository files (or directories) in Azure Devops portal

Tags: azure-devops

The scope of this question is Azure Devops Portal. I know how to do this using git cli.

How can I move repository files (or directories) in Azure Devops portal?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently. What I did was download the file that you want to move to the new folder. Then remove it. Go to the folder that you want to move the downloaded file and upload the file. It worked for me.

Comment: The problem with the delete/create approach is that all the file file history will be lost. I was hoping to find a way that retains the commit history of the file.

Comment: to keep history w/ git repo: `git mv .\azure-pipelines.yml .\pipelines\azure-pipelines.yml`